# How to improve speed in bioinformatics script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m developing a python script for bioinformatic analysis. First, the script reads the entire file (.fasta – which is basically a very long string) to find all the scaffolds (lines that starts with ‘>’), then it prints out the number of scaffolds found. I have two similar input files .fasta, one with over 1.5GB that runs in less than a minute, and a second one with 85MB that takes more than 31 HOURS.

```
import sys

cabecalho = []
sequencia = []
contador = -1
file_open = open('C:\PYTHON\Chr09.fasta', "r")
for line in file_open:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if ">" in line:
        cabecalho.append(line)
        contador += 1
        sequencia.insert(contador, '')
    else:
        sequencia[contador] += line
con = contador + 1
print(con)
```

What can I do to optimize the running speed of this script? Or how can I check what’s wrong with the file (They have the same format, and the same text config.)?

Comment: Statistically speaking, what are the differences between these two files? For example, does one of them have a lot more `>`s than the other one? Does one of them have much longer lines? Does one of them contain a lot of non-ASCII characters?

Comment: `sequencia.insert(contador, '')` is inefficient, rendering your algorithm worst-case quadratic time. Although by the looks of it, it is simply going to `.append`, in which case it should be fine, but `.insert` in a loop is a big red flag for me. Also, `sequencia[contador] += line` is an inefficient way to grow a string... better off using an intermediate `list` then using `''.join` on a final pass.

Comment: @DavidKnipe statistically speaking, the files are the same, the only differences are that the larger one has a lot more > than the smaller one.  Both have 61 characters per line, and neither of them has non-ASCII characters. Whats weird is that the smaller file takes a lot more time to run than the bigger one.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not sure I understood what you meant there. How do you suggest that I rewrite this code?

Comment: If you want us to find out what the differencies between the two files are, you have to upload them somewhere and share a link to them !

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to reinvent the wheel, Biopython can easily handle the fasta files, for example:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

myseqs = {}
fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open('C:\PYTHON\Chr09.fasta'), 'fasta')
for fasta in fasta_sequences:
 name, sequence = fasta.description, str(fasta.seq)
 myseqs[name] = sequence

print("total sequences: "+len(myseqs))
```

In this way you will also have your sequences as a dict to easily access through the fasta header and do whatever you want.

Finally, to install biopython just type

> pip install biopython

Other approach without Python, if you only want to know the number of scaffolds, you can do it in one line using `grep` command in unix enviroment

> grep -c ">" myfasta.fasta

-c is for count match only